# Prevent an app from being ended/killed

Tags: android, alarm

I have a obnoxious alarm that requires me to do a bunch of task to turn it off.
I want to know a way to prevent me from simply ending the app and circumventing the alarm.

Is it possible to do this programmatically (not sure if that a word) or through the default interface/os.

Comment: Unless you build your own version of Android, you can't.

Comment: Clear my confusion, are roms/rooting capable of such a thing? Is there an existing mod/modded os that could do this?

Comment: It's probably impossible for any one person to know the capabilities of  all possible custom ROMs, especially as new ones are created all the time.  I am familiar with 4, none of which do this.  My personal opinion is that no-one has ever done this since it is such an obscure requirement.

Comment: I don't know if you're a custom ROM developer, but, do you happen to know if this certain feature is easily implementable?

Comment: We all use Android system and nobody but you suffers of an obnoxious alarm. Can you figure out what package causes it and uninstall? In the worst scenario you may reset the firmware.

Comment: You misinterpreted what I want. I want an obnoxious alarm. However it is easy to circumvent the alarm by simply ending the process. What I want is a programmatic way to prevent me from ending the app.